# Third party script change test (Hash)

Tags: javascript, html, xss

When including a script in a webpage, is there a way to see if this script changes over time?

For example:

```
<script src="https://thirdparty.com/script.js"></script>
<script>
   // Some code to hash the script contents and store in a variable hashOfScript
   // Then compare to a known version of the script
   if (hashOfScript !== previousHashOfScript) {
      alert('Script has changed!!!');
   }
</script>
```

This is for security purposes.  Basically, I am including a script from a third party site that I generally trust and can inspect their script.  Thereafter, I just want to track it to see if the script ever changes.  Mostly, I want to know if they are grabbing my cookies or reading sensitive data in the DOM.

**EDIT**

One example of this is Google Analytics.  I generally trust Google with my Analytics data and so I am including analytics.js.  However, if someone at Google with access wanted to they could do something like:

```
// PSUEDOCODE HERE
if (requestingSite === interestingData) {
   analytics.js = cookieGrabbingAndDomScrapingAnalytics.js
   send(analytics.js)
}
```

Again this is only one example of a stable JS script that could be changed on a case by case basis maliciously (either by a bad actor within or (less likely) by a man-in-the-middle).

Note:  My entire site and all scripts are loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: if they can man-in-the-middle the library you're loading, I'd somewhat expect them to also know how to man-in-the-middle your HTML so the hash your users compare to is theirs. Far more secure is to not bother with hashing, and rely on serving content on HTTPS, with your libraries loaded from an HTTPS large CDN.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ . You can manually make a function that will make an MD5 hash and compare it to something and when it does not match, call an .PHP script or something on your server.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I updated my question clarifying that everything is over HTTPS.

Comment: Google Analytics *is* grabbing your cookies.

Comment: @PeeHaa I knew GA set and grabbed some cookies.  I didn't realize they grabbed all of them.  Well, I have httpOnly Secure cookies for session information so that's good, but I may have to look into Piwik.